# How can I host a python server script, on a cloud hosted server (Google, Amazon, Azure...)?

Tags: python, server, cloud, hosting, python-requests

let me start by answering the obvious.  Why would I want to do this?  Actually, I don't.  I made the following program below, but it's designed to run on a remote server.  I'm basically using the socket library, but I want to host it on another machine, preferbly a google, amazon, azure, etc.  But, as I knew before I tried, this was slightly not possible.  Google app engine gave me an error, like "access denied to socket blah blah blah".

I feel I'm left with 2 options:

I can continue to run this code on my own servers, if I can figure out how to host this server script on a hosted cloud base server, or I could take the code, every bit that doesn't contain the server portion, and make it get the "data" from the clients, via POST requests.

the data is what's sent from the client...

```
bap = {}
while 1:
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_address = ("localhost", 8081)
    #print 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
    server.bind(server_address)
    server.listen(5)
    connection, client_address = server.accept()
    #print 'connection from', connection.getpeername()
    server.close()
    data = connection.recv(4096)

    if data in bap:
        print data + " is checking in!!!"
        for k, v in bap.iteritems():
            if k == data:
                bap[k] = 10
                print bap
                c = open('check.json', "w")
                wiz = json.dumps(bap)
                c.write(wiz)
                c.close()
            else:
                bap[k] -= 1
                if bap[k] < 0:
                    print k + " is Offline!!!"
                    mail()
                    c = open('log.txt', "a")
                    wiz = json.dumps(bap)
                    time1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M ")
                    c.write(k + " is offline!!! "+ time1 + "\n")
                    c.close()
                else:
                    print bap
    else:
        bap[data] = 10
        print data + " was added!!!"
```

Comment: Not very clear what you want to do? do you want to run this script somewhere and then post data to it from a different machine? And what is `data`?

Comment: I edited a bit better.  Basically, i have clients that uses sockets to connect to the server.  They are sending simple string data via socket connect.  So I want to host the server in the cloud of at my house.

Comment: Do you still want your script to listen on a socket on the cloud server and client to POST data to it? Also unless its a specific requirement for you to use low-level sockets, I would recommend you use simple like `bottle` to run a simple app that can receive an HTTP Post.

Comment: I've heard of bottle recently and will dig more into it.  I'd prefer for it to be in the cloud, available 24/7, it really doesn't matter to me as far as lower level since no important data is being passed, the client is merely checking into the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a python script listening to external ports can be done on Amazon EC2.

1) Create an EC2 Instance using the Management Console at [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/).

2) Edit the Security Group associated with your instance so it opens the port number you want your python script to be listening to.

3) Upload and run your script on the EC2 instance. Be sure the port number that your script is listening on is the same as the one you opened in the Security Group.

If you SSH into your EC2 instance, you may want to run the python script in a "background process" using something like [TMUX](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux). Else when you terminate the SSH connection your python script will stop running.

Comment: That's good to know :)  I'm definitely going to look into it.